# Method returning duplicates.

Tags: c#, linq

I have this method that returns policies and it is returning successfully except that it also returns duplicates.

```
public void GetAllEligibleUnredeemedPoliciesForEachActiveAgentCodeForTheAgent()
    {
        AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode = new List<DtoApp2LeadPolicy>();
        foreach (var agentCode in AllOfTheAgentCodesForTheAgent)
        {
            if (AgentPolicies != null) AgentPolicies.ToList().Clear();
            SetTheAgentCode(agentCode);
            SetAgentPolicyNumbersByAgentCode();
            SetAllPolicyNumbersByAgentsEligiblePolicies();
            SetAgentPoliciesFromAtlamServices();
            if(AgentPolicies != null) AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode.AddRange(AgentPolicies);
        }
    }
```

So i was thinking of adding

```
List<long> unique = longs.Distinct().ToList()
```

My question is A) Is this the correct way to eliminate duplicates? B) Where and how in my method should i plug this in?

I had also attempted this which says it contains an invalid argument.

```
  public void GetAllEligibleUnredeemedPoliciesForEachActiveAgentCodeForTheAgent()
    {
        var AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode = new List<DtoApp2LeadPolicy>();
        foreach (var agentCode in AllOfTheAgentCodesForTheAgent)
        {
            if (AgentPolicies != null) AgentPolicies.ToList().Clear();
            SetTheAgentCode(agentCode);
            SetAgentPolicyNumbersByAgentCode();
            SetAllPolicyNumbersByAgentsEligiblePolicies();
            SetAgentPoliciesFromAtlamServices();
            if(AgentPolicies != null && !AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode.Contains(AgentPolicies))
            {
                AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode.AddRange(AgentPolicies);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: this line won't do anything `AgentPolicies.ToList().Clear();`

Comment: AgentPolicies.ToList().Clear() isn't clearing AgentPolicies. I'm betting this is likely the source of your duplication problem.

Comment: Should i remove it altogether?

Comment: Probably not! At least not entirely. If you mean for the sequence to be clear, then you need to clear the sequence. Given that we can't see the definition of that sequence or how it gets populated and used, we can't give you good direction on how to do that and how it relates to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public void GetAllEligibleUnredeemedPoliciesForEachActiveAgentCodeForTheAgent()
    {
        var AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode = new List<DtoApp2LeadPolicy>();
        foreach (var agentCode in AllOfTheAgentCodesForTheAgent.Distinct())
        {
            if (AgentPolicies != null) AgentPolicies.Clear();
            SetTheAgentCode(agentCode);
            SetAgentPolicyNumbersByAgentCode();
            SetAllPolicyNumbersByAgentsEligiblePolicies();
            SetAgentPoliciesFromAtlamServices();
            if (AgentPolicies != null )
            {
                AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode.AddRange(AgentPolicies);
            }

        }
    }
```

So here you are looping only through unique (distinct) agent codes and you are not adding duplicates to your AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode list. pls try that and let me know

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicates because you are never actually clearing your `AgentPolicies`. `ToList()` creates a new instance of your list, and then you are clearing that one, and losing the reference to it because you didn't cache it in a variable.

just remove the `ToList()` and you should be golden.

```
if (AgentPolicies != null) AgentPolicies.Clear();
```

or you can just do it this way:

```
if (AgentPolicies != null) AgentPolicies = new List<AgentPolicy>();
```

Comment: Tried both of these and could not compile

Comment: What type is `AgentPolicies` ? is it an enumerable? list?